# Returning a new object from within an open DataReader - OK or not?

Tags: c#, .net, datareader

I saw this code:

```
public static ConsTypeCategory GetConsCategory(int providerId, int categoryId) {
    const string select =
        @"SELECT CategoryId, CategoryName, ExpectedDurationMins 
        FROM constypecategories
        WHERE ProviderId = @ProviderId
            AND CategoryId = @CategoryId
        LIMIT 1";
    MySqlParameter[] mySqlParameters = {
        new MySqlParameter("ProviderId", providerId),
        new MySqlParameter("CategoryId", categoryId)
    };
    using (MySqlDataReader dr = MySqlHelper.ExecuteReader(DB.ConnectionString, select, mySqlParameters)) {
        while (dr.Read()) {
            return new ConsTypeCategory(
                dr.GetInt32("CategoryId"),
                dr.GetString("CategoryName"),
                dr.GetInt32("ExpectedDurationMins")
            );
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

...and instantly thought that it was wrong to return the 'new' object from within the datareader loop.  But attempting to find justification for that opinion, I've come up empty.

Is there a good reason not to return from within that 'while'?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this. You even could use that inside an iterator method and return objects one by one with `yield return ...`. The reader would close when it went out of scope. In this case, after the `return`. In an iterator, after iteration stopped

Comment: You can replace while with if in this case, maybe then you'll feel better about that

Comment: You're using a `while` loop but returning the first record. This suggests that you might need to read more than that. Although it's functionally equivalent to using `if`, you should use `if` to make it clear that you only expect it to return one.

Comment: agree with @madreflection.  The next dev to look at your code is going to wonder if there's a bug there.

Comment: The 'while' to 'if' switch makes sense. And thank you all for the education, especially @PanagiotisKanavos for the clarification about the reader behaviour - I think that was the area of my 'made up' concern!